# "Saw a friend get/got an ice cream."

Tags: tense, past-tense, syntax

Earlier today, I wrote:

> "Saw a friend got an ice cream."

However, I was told that it should be:

> "Saw a friend get an ice cream."

Why should *get* be used instead when the sentence refers to the past? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually say "I saw a friend get ice cream"; the "an" is unnecessary but not incorrect. The reason you say *get* instead of *got* in that situation is because the verb *saw* is already past tense.

You are the subject of the sentence and the one who did the seeing. Therefore, you *saw* your friend *get* ice cream. But if someone were to ask you what happened, you would say "my friend got ice cream" since your *friend* is now the subject of the sentence.